# Get referral url on iframe(different domain)?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have iframes in different domains and want to track referral when somebody clicks on iframe, but always getting iframe referral url not real one...

Answer (score 3):

That's because of the **[Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)**. There is **no way around** that for obvious security reasons.